# How to pass variable from Makefile to Python script through docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, variables, makefile, docker-compose

I have a Makefile, that runs a docker-compose, which has a container that executes a python script. I want to be able to pass a variable in the command-line to the Makefile and print it within the python script (`testing.py`).

My directory looks like:

```
main_folder:
  -docker-compose.yaml
  -Makefile
  -testing.py
```

I have tried with the following configuration. The Makefile is:

```
.PHONY: run run-prod stop stop-prod rm

run:
    WORKING_DAG=$(working_dag) docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --remove-orphans --build --force-recreate
```

The docker-compose is:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  prepare_files:
    image: apache/airflow:1.10.14
    environment:
      WORKING_DAG: ${working_dag}
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: -c "python3 testing.py $$WORKING_DAG"
```

And the file testing.py is:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[0], flush=True)
```

When I run in the command line:

```
 make working_dag=testing run
```

It doesn't fail but it does not print anything neither. How could I make it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the variable `WORKING_DAG` is getting assigned correctly through the command-line and `Makefile` is passing it correctly to the `docker-compose`. I verified it by running the container to not be destroyed and then after logging into the container, I checked the value of `WORKING_DAG`:

To not destroy the container once the docker execution is completed, I modified the `docker-compose.yml`, as follows:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  prepare_files:
    image: apache/airflow:1.10.14
    environment:
      WORKING_DAG: ${working_dag}
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: -c "python3 testing.py $$WORKING_DAG"
    command: -c "tail -f /dev/null"
```

---

```
airflow@d8dcb07c926a:/opt/airflow$ echo $WORKING_DAG
testing
```

The issue that `docker` does not display Python's `std.out` when deploying with `docker-compose` was already commented in Github, [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6261), and it still not resolved. Making it work when using `docker-compose`, is only possible if we transfer/mount the file into the container, or if we use `Dockerfile` instead.

When using a `Dockerfile`, you only have to run the corresponding script as follows,

```
CMD ["python", "-u", "testing.py", "$WORKING_DAG"]
```

To mount the script into the container, please look at `@DazWilkin`'s answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66014677/7611357).